# MySQL add 3 hours on update in datetime

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cases` (
  `case_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT utc_timestamp )
```

The server timezone is CET, that means UTC+1 and UTC+2 in summer; while the user interface is Turkey, that is UTC+3 all year.

I don't have permission to change the server timezone nor the session timezone.

Is it possible to add a `DEFAULT` value on insert/on update to the `date` field in a way, that it will always store turkish time?

My idea was something like `DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 HOUR` but my MySQL version is 5.7, that means according to the mysql.com * site I cannot use expression and that's why I am looking for a different solution.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-types-defaults-explicit

Answer (score 1):

1. `case_id` must be defined as PRIMARY KEY
2. `utc_timestamp` function not exists
3. You cannot use expression in DEFAULT, but you may use generated column

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cases` (
  `case_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  utc_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` DATETIME AS (utc_date + INTERVAL 3 HOUR));
```

PS. Remember - changing `utc_date` value will change generated column value accordingly.